# Repeated Zero-Width Lookahead

Tags: regex, c++11

The other day, I started thinking of how a regex engine would be implemented, and one potential problem I came up with involves zero-width lookaheads and repetition. For example, when matching the regex (extra parentheses to avoid invalid syntax) `/((?=x))*/` on the string `"xx"` would try to match the inner group as many times as possible. Since, starting at the beginning of the string, the ZWLA passes, it's considered a match, but doesn't consume any characters. Thus, one might believe the regex engine could enter an infinite loop.

When tested in GNU C++11, `regex_match` returned `false`.

When tested on [regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript), it DID return a match.

Would this kind of regex construct be considered "ill-formed"? Or is there a standard behavior for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this kind of regex construct be considered "ill-formed"? Or is there a standard behavior for this kind of thing?

No, `((?=x))` is a valid regex. It matches an empty string before `x`.

**Why would one want to match an empty string?**
There are situations where one needs to match an empty string. One of the usual applications is ***splitting*** with some kind of `Regex.Split`.

> one might believe the regex engine could enter an infinite loop.

It is indeed an issue worth considering. Most regex engine implementations feature their own mechanism of multiple matching. Most of them move the regex index after each check to the next available position. In JS, you need to use `g` with `match()`, `exec()` (also, `test()` will do this, too) and the engine will advance the `lastIndex` property. All the major languages will do it in a similar way (C# `Regex.Matches`, Java's `while (matcher.find())`, Pythons `re.finditer/re.findall`, etc.). However, sometimes, the index must be moved manually (here is an example in JS that [works](http://jsfiddle.net/sgntu5nq/) and [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/sgntu5nq/1/) will cause the infinite loop).

As for why you got no match in C++, it is easy to explain: the [`regex_match`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) expects the whole string to match. If you use a [`regex_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/), you will get a successful match with an empty string as `/((?=x))*/` regex will match the empty string before the first `x` (if you do not enable multiple searches).

See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/LDXVm8)

```
string data("xx");
std::regex pattern("((?=x))*");
std::smatch result;

if (regex_search(data, result, pattern)) {
    std::cout << "\"" << result[0].str() << "\"" << std::endl;
}
else 
{
    std::cout << "regex_search failed!" << std::endl;   
}
if (regex_match(data, result, pattern)) {
    std::cout << result[0].str() << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "regex_match failed!" << std::endl;    
}
```

Result:

```
""
regex_match failed!
```

Comment: Alright, so that explains why `regex_match` fails, but it doesn't answer my main question about whether this pattern is "bad".

Comment: Why should it be bad? It is a valid regex. Do you mean the point about infinite loop when matching multiple times the same string? It should be implemented in the tegex engine. In C++, you need to do it "manually". In JS, `exec` or `test` will move the re.Index automatically, and so on.

Comment: I'm just thinking about this from an implementation standpoint (as in, how I would implement a regex engine myself) - the problem is how to implement both ZWLA and the `*` quantifier such that I don't enter an infinite loop of matching with the ZWLA but not consuming any characters.

Comment: The best way is to use the approach as in my working JS demo: store  last successful match index, and if the current match index coincides with it, increment the current index.

Comment: Still looking for some more feedback on this?

Comment: Yeah - I'm thinking regex engines simply check for these kind of forms and specially handle them

Comment: Correct, as I described in my answer, each platform deals with them their own way. I think the consensus is to advance the index automatically after a test. JS is considered to have the worst regex engine, I'd rather not chose it as a paragon of regex behavior.